# What is the intended usage of the Sprite class in LibGDX

Tags: libgdx, architecture, sprites

I am making a small game in LibGDX and it all works, sprites are moving etc. The drawing is mainly done in the render() method of a Screen, using Batch.draw(TextureRegion). So far so good.

But now I would like my sprites to rotate. There are Batch draw methods for rotation (I think), but I noticed a bunch of useful methods in tne Sprite class. Problem is I do not know how to use them without making the rest of the program ugly.

I could have a Sprite as a member of each "game object", but that makes direct dependency of the game model on drawing mechanism, specifically LibGDX. Besides I can see problems with serialization and duplicate parameters (Sprite x,y vs model x,y etc) and unnecessary overhead.

Or I could subclass Sprite, which would probably be orders of magnitude messier.

Is there a common way of clearly separating the model part and rendering part of  a small game? And how is Sprite typically used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Sprite` class is just that. A `Sprite`. It represents a texture in 2D space that can be transformed (moved, rotated, scaled) however you like. Think of it as a more sophisticated `Texture` (or `TextureRegion`) class that is used in the same way.

Your characters should probably not extend `Sprite` since your characters *aren't* sprites, they *have* sprites. Hence your character class would *contain* a `Sprite` not *extend* from it.

A minimalistic character class might look something like this:

```
public class Character {
    private float x, y; //Position
    private Sprite sprite;

    public void update() {
        // Before this update character velocity, position, etc...
        sprite.setPosition(this.x, this.y);
    }

    public void draw(Batch batch) {
        // This is how you draw a sprite.
        sprite.draw(batch);
    }
}
```

As for unnecessary overhead and serialization etc. you shouldn't worry. [Premature optimization like that is the bane to everyone's existence](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/141399/why-is-it-so-bad-to-optimize-too-early). But you should never serialize textures of any kind anyways so you should probably make your sprite field `transient` (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/910374/why-does-java-have-transient-fields) if you don't know what `transient` is).

Comment: Yes, this is the approach that first came to mind. It is not too good, but the only other solution I can see is a Drawer class for each type of character and I think java is too verbose for that. The objections are just examples of how bad this design is, not premature optimization. And yes, I know what transient is:)

Comment: I am accepting the answer because no other appeared and because this is what I am doing now. Separate drawing classes may come in later though.